# Extract string after space in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know it is a simple one but I need your help to extract a string after a space in vba (after arrow)
Eg.:

CH 01223 -> 01223

XVC 0212 -> 0212

Comment: ```split(str, " ")(1)```

Comment: i was trying your example: exp_conta.Cells(i, 5) = Split(imp_asig.Cells(i, 12), " ")(1), but i had an error

Comment: An error you say? Did the string you passed to the split function not have a space in it?

Comment: Did you try the example as @Warcupine posted? It is obvious that it works. If yes, this can only mean that your `imp_asig.Cells(i, 12)` value has a problem. It maybe does not have spaces in its string value and, in such a case, the array obtained by `Split` does not exist, Try using `Debug.Print imp_asig.Cells(i, 12).value` before your line. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? Or try: `Debut.Print IsArray(Split(imp_asig.Cells(i, 12).Value, " "))`. Does it return `True`? In fact, if you need the value after arrow, it should be `Split(imp_asig.Cells(i, 12).Value, " ")(3)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Split` function to do that. Just make sure is actually has a space in it first.

```
Dim sTest as String

sTest = "CH 01223"

If Instr(sTest, " ") > 0 Then 
  MsgBox Split(sTest, " ")(1)
Else
  MsgBox sTest & " has no space in it."
End If
```

Or you can check the upper bound first

```
Dim sTest as String
Dim vSplit As Variant

sTest = "CH 01223"

vSplit = Split(sTest, " ")

If UBound(vSplit) = 0 Then
  MsgBox sTest & " has no space in it."
Else
  MsgBox vSplit(1)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Split is very elegant.

Also:

```vb
MsgBox Mid(sTest , InStr(sTest , " ") + 1)
```

will work

Comment: Up-voted but bear in mind that this would only work if there was a single space in the string, I've posted a similar answer but using `Right` and `InStrRev`

Comment: Yeah I meant at least one space, otherwise it returns the whole string same as the one I posted, mine is different in that InStrRev does it for the last space.

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer the good old `Split` technique I just thought I'd add `InStrRev` to the mix, because it doesn't `error` if there isn't a space in the string (so you don't need to do checks), it just returns the whole string if there is no space:

```
Sub example(s As String)
  MsgBox Right(s, Len(s) - InStrRev(s, " "))
End Sub
```